# PHP - Select Row by id from SuperGlobals

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically I am building a CMS, this is some of the code im having problems with

> ```
> $v = $_GET['v'];
> $con=mysqli_connect("*******","****","****","********");
>
> // Check connection
> if (mysqli_connect_errno())
>   {
>   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
> }
> $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM videos WHERE `v` = '$v'");
>
> while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
>   {
>    $title = $row['title'];
>    $description = $row['description'];
>    $views = $row['viewcount'];
>    $video_src = $row['src'];
>    $type = $row['embed_type'];
>    if($type = "YouTube"){
>    $yt_id = $row['yt_id'];
>    }
>   }
> ?>
> ```

This isnt returning any values!

Comment: what data u were expect? database result?

Comment: Perhaps nothing matches. Look out for SQL Injection from that unescaped user data.

Comment: the id im using video.php?id=1 and in the sql table the id 1 has a title value of test, im trying to get it the <title>Tag as Test</title>

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to return, but what I know for sure is it will return a sqlinjection. [Learn more about SQLinjection and how to protect yourself](http://idiallo.com/blog/2013/12/sqlinjection-and-sqlprotection)

Comment: If you're using `video.php?id=1` then nothing will match - you're trying to match on `$_GET['v']` but supplying `$_GET['id']`